# Error 99 - permission denied in last.fm php API call

Tags: php, api, last.fm

I'm making a call to retrieve a user's latest tracks using the last.fm PHP api library. It works perfectly when I run it on my local webserver (localhost), but when I run it on a remote server it sends back an error code of 99, saying that permission has been denied.

Here is my code:

```
static function readRecentTracks() {
    $authVars['apiKey'] = '#########';
    $auth = new lastfmApiAuth('setsession', $authVars);
    $apiClass = new lastfmApi();
    $packageClass = $apiClass->getPackage($auth, 'user');
    $method_vars = array(
        'user' => 'liquidus219',
        'limit' => 25
    );

    if ($tracks = $packageClass->getRecentTracks($method_vars)) {
        echo json_encode($tracks);
    } else {
        echo '<b>Error '.$packageClass->error['code'].' - </b><i>'.$packageClass->error['desc'].'</i>';
    }
}
```

You can see the code in action at http://liquidus219.freehostia.com/api/?q=readRecentTracks

UPDATE: I have checked/changed the application URL to no effect.

UPDATE: I have gone through the code for the last.fm PHP api, no sign of an error 99 defined anywhere.

Comment: When you signed up to get the api key did you have to specify any url you would be making requests from?

Comment: I just had to enter the URL of my application - I have achieved it using JavaScript but switched to using PHP.

Comment: Have you updated the URL of the app since uploading it to your remote server?

Comment: I just now updated it to include the api folder, still nothing - my URL is liquidus219.freehostia.com/api/ - and still works fine on my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out in the end that my hosting provider was blocking the call.